# Setting a timeout until Observable's data completes

Tags: java, rx-java

There is a  `rx.Observable.timeout` but it's per item and not for all data.
But I need a timeoutexception if data is not emitted within specific period of time.

```
final Subscriber<Integer> sub = new Subscriber<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer num) {


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                System.out.println(num);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                System.out.println("--------------- Done ---------------");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                //System.out.println("Error!!! + e");
            }
        };

        Observable.range(1, 10000)
        .map(x -> x * 10)
        //.last()
        .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .doOnError( e -> {System.out.println("Errrorrr " + e);})
        .subscribe(sub);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `takeUntil(Observable)` with `timer()` mapped into an exception:

```
source.takeUntil(
    Observable.timer(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMap(ignored -> Observable.error(new TimeoutException()))
)
.subscribe(/* ... */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two sources: one emitting your data, one throwing  your timeout exception after a delay. Merge the two:

```
Observable timeoutObservable = Observable.error(new TimeoutException())
    .delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, true);
return Observable.merge(dataObservable, timoutObservable);
```

Comment: Only like that, it's not very elegant solution for a problem, anyway why delay method? and there is no boolean param for delay...

Comment: Add merge, timeout not invoked

Comment: I was refering to the rxjava javadoc. Assuming that your dataObservable completes, that the timeout observable does delay the error (was the purpose of the boolean param), and that the merge operator completes when any of the observable completes, this should work as expected.